# Prove that for each $x \in\mathbb R$, $(f \circ f)(x) = 2f(x).$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

$f(x)=\lfloor 2x \rfloor$

prove that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $(f \circ f)(x) = 2f(x)$.

$(f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x))$

$f(f(x))=2f(x)$

$\lfloor 2(\lfloor 2x \rfloor)\rfloor = 2(\lfloor 2x \rfloor)$

this is as far as ive gotten so far, can anyone help me figure this one out? in previous parts of this question i showed that this function is not one to one and is surjective if that means anything here...

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lfloor 2x \rfloor$ is an integer, so $2\lfloor 2x \rfloor$ is also an integer; hence $\lfloor 2\lfloor 2x \rfloor \rfloor = 2\lfloor 2x \rfloor$.